# How to uniformly sample multiple numbers whose product is within some bound

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

Suppose I have 3 positive integers: $n_1$, $n_2$, and $n_3$.

How do I uniformly sample $(n_1, n_2, n_3)$ so that $50 < n_1 n_2 n_3 < 100$.

I could sample each number independently with bounds between 1 and 100, then keep re-sampling if their product is out of bound.

I need to do this with a computer program with more numbers and larger bounds, so I prefer a way that's efficient both in space and time.

Are there other ways to sample than what I described above?

EDIT (regarding the accepted answer):

At the time of this edit, there were 3 approaches answered so far:

- complete enumeration (addresses the example in the question, simple, but space and time bound for very large problems)
- rejection sampling (simple, but time bound for very large problems)
- weighted draw ("efficient" in space and time compared to other approaches, but complex)

All answers work best in different situations.

I accepted weighted drawing since it seemed to be most complete in a sense that it addressed the "efficient both in space and time" part for larger problems the best.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniformly" here?

Comment: What kind of numbers? Integers? Reals? Are they required to be positive?

Comment: @user6247850 Please let me know if I'm using the wrong terminology so that I can edit the question. I meant that each tuple `(n1, n2, n3)` has the same probability of being chosen.

Comment: @Arthur Positive integers. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Incidentally (and I'll try and amend my answer if I have time), you can also use a combination of techniques. For instance, if you can generate uniformly in the $1 \leq \prod_in_i\leq b_{max}$ domain (which I believe can be done even more efficiently using some extensions of the technique I suggest), then you can use rejection to throw away everything with $b_{min}\leq\prod_in_i$. efficiently enough (as this will generally throw away a roughly constant fraction of the bounded-above volume).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how large your bounds are, what you consider 'efficient', and how much preprocessing you're willing to do, one option is to do a *weighted* draw of $n_1$. For each $n_1$ you can compute how many $(n_2,n_3)$ pairs yield $b_{min}\leq n_1n_2n_3\leq b_{max}$; this will take $O(b_{max}^2)$ time and $O(b_{max})$ space naively. Then build a CDF table of $n_1$ from those pairs; this will ensure the appropriate probability for that variable. Once you have $n_1$ you can either do the same procedure a dimension down (but note that the tables there will be $n_1$ dependent, so you'll have to build them after choosing $n_1$ or have them available for many possible $n_1$) or do rejection sampling, though presumably with a much smaller range.

For an example, suppose we have $5\leq n_1n_2n_3\leq 10$. Then we start by making a table $T(i)$ of the number of pairs $a,b$ with $1\leq ab\leq i$, for $1\leq i\leq 10$; this looks like $[1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 23, 27]$. (This table is buildable in $O(i^2)$ time through several means and I suspect it's buildable much faster than that in practice if you wanted to dig into the appropriate algorithms.) Now, for each $n_1$ we can compute $T(\lfloor\frac{10}{n_1}\rfloor)-T(\lceil\frac5{n_1}\rceil-1)$ (taking $T(0)=0$); this represents how many pairs $n_2,n_3$ fit the product within the bounds for that $n_1$. This table will look like $[19, 7, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$. Then sampling from this table is a matter of computing the CDF (which here would be $[19, 26, 30, 32, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]$), computing an $r$ uniformly in $[1\ldots 40]$ and doing the reverse lookup to find the corresponding value of $n_1$.

Comment: The example helped a lot! So if I understand correctly, I can build this up to handle more numbers. Each level, I need another $O(b_{max})$ space and $O(b_{max}^2)$ time to precompute the table. It's like adding another number to the multiplication.

Comment: @Russell I believe that's so. That said, this problem has almost certainly been studied before and I wouldn't be surprised if there were good references out there.

Answer (score 6):

There are only 871 such tuples of positive integers $x,y,z$ that $50<xyz<100$.

I believe you can precalculate them and select randomly from the list.

Comment: This definitely works. In the more general case, when the bound goes up to 100000 with 3 numbers, I think this will become prohibitively expensive on modern CPUs. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: I count 7518850 tuples such that $1 < xyz < 100000$, so it wouldn't be entirely crazy to precalculate.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Actually a good point. Thanks.

Comment: Say we want to find all 3-tuples $(x, y, z)$ of positive integers.  such that $m \le xyz \le M$.  Loop over all $x$ from $1$ to $M$. inside that loop, loop over $y$ from $1$ to $\lfloor M/x \rfloor$.  The tuples you want, for give values of $x$ and $y$, are just those with $z$ from $\lceil m/xy \rceil$ to $\lfloor M/xy \rfloor$ and there are $\lfloor M/xy \rfloor - \lceil m/xy \rceil + 1$ of them.

Comment: @MichaelLugo I just tried this. It works for bound 100000 up to 5 numbers which takes about one minute on my machine and counts about 130+ million tuples (at least 2GB space for 4 byte numbers). I guess this is this approaches limit on a personal computer, but actually it is not too crazy as you said. Thanks for making this more concrete.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't an answer per se, but it's too long for a comment. Rejection methods could work well for choosing $n$-tuples whose product is less than $b_{max}$ if those numbers are small.  However, if $b_{max}$ or $n$ get large, the efficiency of the method drops dramatically. We can estimate the number of $n$-tuples whose product is between $b_{max}$ and $b_{min}$ by the volume of the sets of $n$ real numbers greater than $1$ whose product is between those values. This can be done with an iterated integral$^1$:
\begin{multline}
\int_1^{b_{max}}\int_1^{b_{max}/x_1}\int_1^{b_{max}/x_1x_2}...\int_1^{b_{max}/x_1x_2...x_{n-1}}\int_{b_{min}/x_1x_2...x_n}^{b_{max}/x_1x_2...x_n}dx_1dx_2...dx_n\\  = \frac{b_{max}-b_{min}}{(n-1)!}\ln(b_{max})^{n-1}.
\end{multline}
Meanwhile, the total number of $n$-tuples with maximum value $b_{max}$ is, of course, $b_{max}^n$. So if you pick a random $n$-tuple, the probability of it being valid is approximately
$$
P(b_{min}\le x_1x_2...x_n\le b_{max}) \approx\frac{1-\frac{b_{max}}{b_{min}}}{(n-1)!}\left[\frac{\ln(b_{max})}{b_{max}}\right]^{n-1}
$$
As you can see, if $n$ or $b_{max}$ is big, this gets small very quickly. Using the parameters you've mentioned in your question and comments, for $b_{max} = 100$, $n = 3$ it's about $10^{-3}$. For $b_{max} = 10^5$, $n=3$ it's about $10^{-8}$. And for $b_{max} = 10^5$, $n= 6$ it's about $10^{-22}$.

$^1$Strictly speaking the lower limit of the innermost integral should be $\max(b_{min}/x_1x_2...x_n,1)$. But this is only an approximation anyways, and at any rate it only makes the probabilities worse.

Comment: Thanks so much for deriving this. I was about to ask some follow up questions about determining the effectiveness of rejection sampling. This is indeed helpful.

Answer (score 5):

There's a really simple method that achieves uniformity automatically, but is likely to be somewhat slow, namely "rejection sampling":

the three numbers must all be between $1$ and $100$, so do the following:

1. Select three numbers, $p,q,r$, uniformly between $1$ and $100$. Compute their product $K = pqr$.
2. If $50 \le K \le 100$, return the triple $(p, q, r)$.
3. Otherwise, return to step 1.

Now as @VasilyMitch has observed, there are about $1000 = 10^3$ "good" triples, but there $10^6$ possible triples, so on average, you'll need to perform step 1 about $1000$ times to succeed at step 2.

Fortunately, computer time is cheap, and debugging programs is hard, so writing simple code like this can be a win (depending on your circumstances).

You can, of course, do much better with a nearly equivalent strategy: rather than sampling uniformly from a cube that contains all the good triples, you could sample uniformly from some smaller shape --- an axis-aligned tetrahedron, for instance, and probably reduce the number of wasted attempts by a factor of 6. Then again, you'd be increasing the complexity and maintainance cost for your program as well.

Comment: Thanks for the keywords "rejection sampling" and "axis-aligned tetrahedron". Looks like I have some more reading to do. My worst use case has 6 numbers and bound 100000, so I may need to rethink the requirements. This approach would work for most of my use cases.